# Wordpress: Submit form from within a plugin to a different database and table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, forms, plugins

Firstly, thank you to all of you who do take the time to read this question. I have never used this service before so looking forward to any support you can give me.

I am currently trying to create a form that handles a single tutor's availability. An example image of the current form is presented below:
[Current Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66vUa.jpg)

The above form is located within a plugin directory. The whole purpose of this is to be able to display current availability on the website but update it via the admin panel. An example of my table on the front end is displayed below: [Front-end Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXeZi.jpg)

My problem is, I cannot get the form to submit the values to the database. I am probably doing it all wrong and need someone to guide me.

My current plugin:

```
/* DESCRIPTION: ADDS PGB TIMESLOTS LINK TO ADMIN DASHBOARD MENU */

add_action('admin_menu', 'pgb_timeslots');
function pgb_timeslots() {
    $page_title = 'PGB Timeslot Management';
    $menu_title = 'PGB Timeslots';
    $capability = 'edit_posts';
    $menu_slug = 'pgb_timeslots';
    $function = 'pgb_timeslot_options';
    $icon_url = '';
    $position = 2;

    add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position );
}

function pgb_timeslot_options() {

  include('sp-db-connect.php'); //Student Portal DB Connection

if (isset($_POST['Update'])) {
        $size = count($_POST['ID']);

        $i = 0;
        while ($i < $size) {
            $mon = $_POST['1'][$i];
            $tues = $_POST['2'][$i];
            $wed = $_POST['3'][$i];
            $thurs = $_POST['4'][$i];
            $fri = $_POST['5'][$i];
            $sat = $_POST['6'][$i];
            $sun = $_POST['7'][$i];
            $id = $_POST['ID'][$i];

            $timetable_update_stmt = $db->prepare('
            UPDATE
                timetable
            SET
                `1` = '.$mon.',
                `2` = '.$tues.', 
                `3` = '.$wed.', 
                `4` = '.$thurs.', 
                `5` = '.$fri.', 
                `6` = '.$sat.', 
                `7` = '.$sun.' 
            WHERE 
                timeid = '.$id.' 
            LIMIT 
                1
            ');
            $timetable_update_stmt->execute();
            ++$i;
        }
        // NEED TO SET NOTIFICATION STATUS
        echo '<p>Update Completed</p>';
    }
echo '<style>
/* --- The Table Structure --- */
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
table tr th,
table tr td {
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #e5dfcc;
}
table tr th:first-child,
table tr td:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #bbb;
}
table tr th {
  border-top: 1px solid #bbb;
}

/* top-left border-radius */
table tr:first-child th:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
}

/* top-right border-radius */
table tr:first-child th:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}

/* bottom-left border-radius */
table tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}

/* bottom-right border-radius */
table tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}

/* -- The Stlyes -- */
input[type="text"] {
    width: 100%;
}

th, td{
  padding: 8px 8px;
}
th{
  background: #E5E6EB;
  color: #111;
}
td{
  background: #EFF1F6;
}
</style>';

    echo '<h1>PGB Timeslot Management</h1>
<p>This page allows you to update the available timeslots for PGB. If you enter 0, it means not available, 1 means available weekly, and 2 means available fortnightly.</p>
<section class="timeslots">
<form name="timeslots" method="POST">
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Slots</th>
            <th>Mon</th>
            <th>Tue</th>
            <th>Wed</th>
            <th>Thu</th>
            <th>Fri</th>
            <th>Sat</th>
            <th>Sun</th>
        </tr>';

    $count = 1;
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM timetable';
    $result = mysqli_query($sp_db, $sql) or die($sp_db->error);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        echo '<tr>';
        $halftime = "";

        if (strpos($row['timeid'], 'h') !== false) {                                                
            $halftime = "1";
            $chopme = chop($row['timeid'],"h");
            $nextslot = $chopme+1;
        } else {                                                
            $halftime = "0";                                            
            $chopme = $row['timeid'];
            $nextslot = $row['timeid']+1;
        }

        if ( $halftime == "0" ) {
            //starts on the hour
            echo "<td>".$chopme.":00 - ".$chopme.":30</td>";
        } else {
            //starts on the half hour
            echo "<td>".$chopme.":30 - ".$nextslot.":00</td>";
        }


        echo '<input type="hidden" name="ID[]" value="'.$row['timeid'].'">';                                    
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++) {
            // 1 through 7 = Mon through Sun
            echo '<td><input type="text" name="'.$i.'[]" id="'.$row['timeid'].'" value="'.$row[$i].'"></td>';
        }

        echo '</tr>';
        $count++; 

    } 


    echo '</tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" name ="Update" value="Update" />
<p>Once you have changed the values for availability above, click the update button.</p>
</form>
</section>
</div>
            </div>';

}
```

The above code does not submit anything to the database and presents an empty screen as if there is no admin content to display. After the submit button is clicked, it does not reload the form or save data to the database. When the values are pulled from the database on the front-end table, I convert the output based on the value presented. 0 = full, 1 = weekly, 2 = fortnightly etc.

Am I totally missing something here?

EDIT:

I thought I would provide the current table structure so you can see what I am currently working with:

```
CREATE TABLE `timetable` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Primary ID',
  `timeid` varchar(4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Time-Slot',
  `1` int(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Monday',
  `2` int(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Tuesday',
  `3` int(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Wednesday',
  `4` int(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Thursday',
  `5` int(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Friday',
  `6` int(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Saturday',
  `7` int(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Sunday'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The 'timeid' consists of 7, 7h, 8, 8h, 9, 9h etc. The 'h' lets me know that the slots are starting on the half hour mark. I then convert these into readable time formats on the front-end using the code below:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Slots</th>
            <th>Mon</th>
            <th>Tue</th>
            <th>Wed</th>
            <th>Thu</th>
            <th>Fri</th>
        </tr>
<?php

    include('sp-db-connect.php'); // DB Connection

    $count = 1;
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM timetable';
    $result = mysqli_query($sp_db, $sql) or die($sp_db->error);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        echo '<tr>';
        $halftime = "";

        if (strpos($row['timeid'], 'h') !== false) {                                                
            $halftime = "1";
            $chopme = chop($row['timeid'],"h");
            $nextslot = $chopme+1;
        } else {                                                
            $halftime = "0";                                            
            $chopme = $row['timeid'];
            $nextslot = $row['timeid']+1;
        }

        if ( $halftime == "0" ) {
            //starts on the hour
            echo "<td>".$chopme.":00 - ".$chopme.":30</td>";
        } else {
            //starts on the half hour
            echo "<td>".$chopme.":30 - ".$nextslot.":00</td>";
        }

        for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
            // 1 through 5 = Mon through Fri
            if ($row[$i] == '0' ) {
                $row[$i] = 'Full';
            } elseif ($row[$i] == '1' ) {
                $row[$i] = '<a href="booking-confirmation/?d='.$i.'&t='.$row['timeid'].'&f=1" title="Book Now" rel="nofollow">Weekly</a>';
            } else {
                $row[$i] = '<a href="booking-confirmation/?d='.$i.'&t='.$row['timeid'].'&f=2" title="Book Now" rel="nofollow">Every 2 weeks</a>';
            }
        }

        for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
            // 1 through 5 = Mon through Fri
            echo "<td>".$row[$i]."</td>";
        }

        echo '</tr>';
        $count++; 

    } 


?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I don't want to create a fully functional planner/schedule. I need to display the timeslots on the front-end and then indicate whether they are available or not. I understand your logic about formatting and only needing to store the unavailable data in the DB. I am not too sure how I could use the 'booking_start' and 'booking_end' variables to get that data.

The user will be clicking on a timeslot which will redirect to a booking form. That timeslot gets passed to the new page for them to confirm. The timeslots do not change. I don't need to get specific dates etc. All I need is set timeslots each week and whether they are available or not. If somebody takes a timeslot on a specific day, I then just need to be able to mark it as full. The reason is, if somebody does take that slot on a day, they will have that slot constantly.

It's basically music tuition slots. Students would book a slot and have that same slot each week. When new students want to see my availability, they just need to know which slots I have available etc and which are full.

Comment: I basically need a way to update the values in the database so I can display the availability on the front-end. If anyone knows a far simpler way to accomplish my goal, please go ahead and put me in my place.

Comment: this looks like poor design

Comment: Do you have anything more helpful than that?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but wanted to take advantage of formatting options...

Ok, well we know that all slots mon-fri, 7.00 - 23.00 exist, so we don't need to store those. We only need to store those that are unavailable. So our table could look like this:

```
( user_id INT NOT NULL
, booking_start DATETIME NOT NULL
, booking_end DATETIME NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY (user_id,booking_start)
)
```

Whether or not this is the ultimate design is up to you, but it is at least normalised, which your present design isn't.

Comment: Thank you for posting a response that deals with my formatting. If I understand you correctly, are you saying that I do not need to store the available slots because we already know they exist. I only need to store the unavailable slots and then pull those from the database for the front-end. How would I know which day is which and to which slots they belong?

Comment: Yes. You store the datetime start and datetime end.